# Communicating between NodeJS and C using node-ipc and unix sockets

Tags: c, node.js, sockets, ipc, node-ipc

I want to communicate between NodeJS and a C program using [node-ipc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-ipc), over a Unix socket, which according to that homepage is the fastest option. (They will be on the same machine). That package claims it could communicate with a C program. (I had to sanity check).

The problem is [the examples](https://github.com/RIAEvangelist/node-ipc/tree/master/example/unixWindowsSocket/basic) don't give example C code, and I have next to no idea how I'd get them to talk.

Can anyone point me to an example of C code to match those client/server examples? For example, [how would I adapt this tutorial on working with unix pipes in C](https://users.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave.Marshall/C/node23.html) (Assuming I'm not completely off track?! Maybe it's "[domain sockets](https://troydhanson.github.io/network/Unix_domain_sockets.html)" that I want instead?) None of this is making any sense to me, I'm missing something crucial.

Comment: Are you trying to communicate the programs in both directions? Is this a commercial project? Would you pay for help?

Comment: Yes, both directions. Paying for help isn't really an option, I just need a nudge in the right direction. I was going to use ZeroMQ but it seems like total overkill

Comment: If it's on a POSIX system, it's a very simple task in fact. Sadly, I can't help you for free, or answering here since I consider that you need more than simple help. Unix Domain Sockets is the way to go, and I am sure if you google it right you will find plenty of examples with c code included. And it's a very simple thing in fact, just like a regular socket but with a different address and type.

Comment: C has no significant here. You just need a language that can make system calls. If you're speaking over the network, it really doesn't matter what language you use.

Comment: I would like to request more information about this, are you able/willing to share your project so I can learn more?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I got it to work in the end with the code below. You can have it for free!

**server.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *socket_path = "/tmp/icp-test";

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  struct sockaddr_un addr;
  char buf[100];
  int fd,cl,rc;

  if (argc > 1) socket_path=argv[1];

  if ( (fd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
    perror("socket error");
    exit(-1);
  }

  memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
  addr.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
  if (*socket_path == '\0') {
    *addr.sun_path = '\0';
    strncpy(addr.sun_path+1, socket_path+1, sizeof(addr.sun_path)-2);
  } else {
    strncpy(addr.sun_path, socket_path, sizeof(addr.sun_path)-1);
    unlink(socket_path);
  }

  if (bind(fd, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) == -1) {
    perror("bind error");
    exit(-1);
  }

  if (listen(fd, 5) == -1) {
    perror("listen error");
    exit(-1);
  }

  while (1) {
    if ( (cl = accept(fd, NULL, NULL)) == -1) {
      perror("accept error");
      continue;
    }

    while ( (rc=read(cl,buf,sizeof(buf))) > 0) {
      printf("read %u bytes: %.*s\n", rc, rc, buf);
    }
    if (rc == -1) {
      perror("read");
      exit(-1);
    }
    else if (rc == 0) {
      printf("EOF\n");
      close(cl);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

***client.js:***

```
 var ipc=require('node-ipc');

var socketId = 'icp-test';
ipc.config.id   = 'hello';
ipc.config.socketRoot = '/tmp/';
ipc.config.appspace = '';

ipc.config.retry= 1500;
ipc.connectTo(
  socketId,
  function(){
    ipc.of[socketId].on(
      'connect',
      function(){
        console.log("Connected!!");
        ipc.log('## connected to world ##'.rainbow, ipc.config.delay);
        ipc.of[socketId].emit(
          'message',  //any event or message type your server listens for
          'hello'
        )
      }
    );
    ipc.of[socketId].on(
      'disconnect',
      function(){
        console.log("Disconnected!!");
        ipc.log('disconnected from world'.notice);
      }
    );
    ipc.of[socketId].on(
      'message',  //any event or message type your server listens for
      function(data){
        console.log("Got a message!!");
        ipc.log('got a message from world : '.debug, data);
      }
    );
  }
);
```

On a side note, I've realised that if you just want to do communicate between NodeJS via unix sockets with C, NodeJS actually comes with [a module that does that already](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_server_listen_path_backlog_callback). Which as it turns out, is what `node-ipc` uses under the hood. So it might be easier just to use NodeJS's `net` package instead. 
[This previous question points out how to do IPC in NodeJS.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7045614/can-node-js-listen-on-unix-socket) Just combine that with the above C code.

Comment: ``#include <string.h>`` to squelch some warnings

Comment: @Jodes - this is really helpful! How did you achieve the two way communication? How do you pass data from the c server to the client? Also, my goal is to use express on the client so that it will receive requests and at some point to pass some work to the c server. Do you have any idea if the requests will be namespaced or do I need threads?

Comment: @Jodes I have asked a question to clarify passing data in the reverse direction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52755754/communicating-between-c-and-nodejs-using-node-ipc-and-unix-sockets

Answer (score 4):

I think that you should be looking for C unix domain sockets, not pipes.  Pipes are different.  Look for some C code examples on Google with unix domain sockets, try a few out, get that working, then go back to the node-ipc stuff.

I took the node-ipc and node.js tags off because Node isn't relevant if you are trying to figure out the C side first.