# Communicating between C and NodeJS using node-ipc and unix sockets

Tags: node.js, unix-socket, node-ipc

This question follows on from the following:

[Communicating between NodeJS and C using node-ipc and unix sockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39841942/communicating-between-nodejs-and-c-using-node-ipc-and-unix-sockets)

In regards to the accepted solution (https://stackoverflow.com/a/39848936/1834057), I was wondering if someone might be able to clarify exactly how to send data from *C to Node.js*. The solution demonstrates sending data from *Node.js to C*, but not in reverse. I have an application that requires two-way communications, so the missing component is critical for me.

My understanding of unix sockets that one of either `write`, `send` or `sendmsg` should be able to do the job, however, I am not having any luck. If this understanding is incorrect, please advise.

In order to get a trivial example running, lets say when a message is read in the C code, lets send back a message and try to trigger the `ipc.of[socketId].on('message',...)` event on the node server.

Which means I am trying to turn this:

```
while ( (rc=read(cl,buf,sizeof(buf))) > 0) {
      printf("read %u bytes: %.*s\n", rc, rc, buf);
}
```

Into this:

```
while ( (rc=read(cl,buf,sizeof(buf)) ) > 0) {
  printf("read %u bytes: %.*s\n", rc, rc, buf);

  //Respond to the node server
  int n;
  char * msg = "{\"type\":\"message\",\"data\":\"hello response\"}\t";
  if((n = write(fd,msg,sizeof(msg))) < 0){
      printf("send failed\n");
  }else{
      printf("sent %d bytes\n", n);
  }
}
```

This would mean that the complete **server.c** code now becomes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h> //Missing from original server.c

char *socket_path = "/tmp/icp-test";

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  struct sockaddr_un addr;
  char buf[100];
  int fd,cl,rc;

  if (argc > 1) socket_path=argv[1];

  if ( (fd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
    perror("socket error");
    exit(-1);
  }

  memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
  addr.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
  if (*socket_path == '\0') {
    *addr.sun_path = '\0';
    strncpy(addr.sun_path+1, socket_path+1, sizeof(addr.sun_path)-2);
  } else {
    strncpy(addr.sun_path, socket_path, sizeof(addr.sun_path)-1);
    unlink(socket_path);
  }

  if (bind(fd, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) == -1) {
    perror("bind error");
    exit(-1);
  }

  if (listen(fd, 5) == -1) {
    perror("listen error");
    exit(-1);
  }

  while (1) {
    if ( (cl = accept(fd, NULL, NULL)) == -1) {
      perror("accept error");
      continue;
    }

    while ( (rc=read(cl,buf,sizeof(buf)) ) > 0) {
      printf("read %u bytes: %.*s\n", rc, rc, buf);

      //Respond to the node server
      int n;
      char * msg = "{\"type\":\"message\",\"data\":\"hello response\"}\t";
      if((n = write(fd,msg,sizeof(msg))) < 0){
          printf("send failed\n");
      }else{
          printf("sent %d bytes\n", n);
      }
    }

    if (rc == -1) {
      perror("read");
      exit(-1);
    }
    else if (rc == 0) {
      printf("EOF\n");
      close(cl);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Now unfortunately, the write message for me returns code `-1`, and is not received by the node.js server.

The **client.js** code remains unchanged, and is as provided in the original question.

Can someone please clarify what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You have to change

```
char * msg = "{\"type\":\"message\",\"data\":\"hello response\"}\t";
if((n = write(fd,msg,sizeof(msg))) < 0){
    printf("send failed\n");
}else{
    printf("sent %d bytes\n", n);
}
```

to

```
char * msg = "{\"type\":\"message\",\"data\":\"hello response\"}\f";
if((n = write(cl,msg,strlen(msg))) < 0){
    printf("send failed\n");
}else{
    printf("sent %d bytes\n", n);
}
```

The library is waiting for **\f** at the end of the message :-)

hope the answer is not too late :-)